# bones constraints breaking skeleton

Tags: bone.constraints

I'm currently trying to figure out how to properly set up a rig (if that's what it's called ?)
I've got a 3d model with a skeleton in blender. I can move the bones just fine, but if I move a bone on any of the linear axis, it's parent bone won't follow behind it (hand bone goes up, forearm bone stays put, mesh is torn appart...).
I've tried to add "child of" bone constraints, to make the parent bone follow the child, but doing so somehow moves the bones in a direction whenever I add a constraint (and it remains even if I remove the constraint).

I'm not actually sure I'm looking in the right direction; I'd just like to be able to move the hand bone and have the rest of the arm bones follow behind it properly, for example...
I've tried to look at a few videos, but I don't know if what I'm searching is correct or not, so I'd be grateful if someone could enlighten me.

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Search for IK and FK (Inverse Kinematic and Forward Kinematic), and learn how to use the IK Bone Constraint.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I've edited the title (hopefully) accordingly.
Will check IK & FK, thank you for the help.